# I want to update script PATH permanently in bash_profile or profile or cshrc based on the shell which user using in script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I have created RPM. After installing RPM,i have to run script which is in /home/data/ directory. If i try to run script.sh from root directory, i got script.sh was not found. To run the script from any location i have to add the path in bash_profile. Planning to add path in Post installation script.
Here i want to check which shell is using and based on that shell path needs to add particular env directory.
For Ex : if user using ksh shell
 echo 'export PATH=$PATH:/home/data'  >> ~/.profile
If user using bash shell
echo 'export PATH=$PATH:/home/data'  >> ~/.bash_profile
like this i want to add path for all the shell(Bourne shell (sh)
C shell (csh)
TC shell (tcsh)
Korn shell (ksh)
Bourne Again shell (bash)). 
How can i do it through bash script?

Comment: It is not the job of an RPM to modify the user's environment, only a way to track what files are installed and where. `/home/data` is not a standard place for executables; you might consider having your RPM install the script someplace users will already have in their path, like `/usr/bin`.

Comment: It's not part of an RPM. But if i add environment variables based on shell in post installation script. It will update into environment directory.. i.e, bash_profile. /home/data is not actual executable place. I just added for ex.